# Python find peaks - wrong x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

i got the following code:

```
Frequency = df['x [Hz]']
Spectrum = df['test_spec']

x = Spectrum
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=20)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "xr"); plt.plot(x); plt.legend(['distance'])
plt.show()
```

The variable "Frequency" contains the frequencies of an a third band octave band spectrum from 5 - 315 HZ. "Spectrum" contains the associated Noisepressurelevels. Now i want to find peaks in that spectrum. the Value i need is the Frequency, where the peak is located.

The problem is that the plot shows a x-axis with the steps 0,5,10,15, but i want a x-axis-scale with my Frequencies saved in the variable "Frequency".

Hope you can help me.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [find_peaks()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) can be a bit confusing, as it calls its input `x` while in most situations that input would be drawn on the y-axis. `find_peaks()` doesn't care about the x-axis, supposing it is just the same as an array index (`0,1,2,...`).

To draw your curve, you need to plot using `Frequency` on the x-axis, and `Spectrum` on the y-axis. You can visualize the peaks by using them as an index in both arrays:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np

Frequency = np.linspace(5, 315, 200)
Spectrum = np.random.randn(200).cumsum()
Spectrum += 1 - Spectrum.min()

peaks, _ = find_peaks(Spectrum, distance=20)
plt.plot(Frequency[peaks], Spectrum[peaks], "xr")
plt.plot(Frequency, Spectrum)
plt.legend(['distance'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! I have been stuck on this one for an hour! And all examples I found online ignore this little, but important detail.